# ClickHouse, find ads with first event "click"

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with columns [datetime, ad_id, event, platform], where

ad_id - id of advertisement

event - {'view', 'click'}

platform - {'web', 'android', 'ios'}

I want to find ad_ids which were clicked before viewed.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ad_id, 
       minIf(datetime, event = 'click' and datetime is not Null) clicktime,
       minIf(datetime, event = 'view' and datetime is not Null) viewtime
from events
group by ad_id
having clicktime <> 0 and clicktime  < viewtime
```

Comment: Thank you. But  "clicktime" and "viewtime" have null values. How can i remove it? For some reason, isNotNull (clicktime) doesn't work.

Comment: `select
           t.ad_id,  
           t.clicktime,   
           t.viewtime
from
(select ad_id,
       minIf(time, event = 'click') clicktime,
       minIf(time, event = 'view') viewtime
from ads_data
group by ad_id) t
where t.clicktime is not null and t.clicktime < t.viewtime`

Comment: The full query is:

`select
    t.ad_id,
    t.clicktime,
    t.viewtime
from
(select ad_id,
       minIf(time, event = 'click' and time is not Null) clicktime,
       minIf(time, event = 'view' and time is not Null) viewtime
from ads_data
group by ad_id) t
where isnotnull(t.clicktime) and t.clicktime < t.viewtime`

Null values exists after grouping operation (e.g. ad_id has no click events) and "isnotnull" doesn't remove it after grouping.

Comment: Your client DBGrip shows 0 time as Null. That is not correct. `HAVING clicktime <> 0  AND (clicktime < viewtime)`

Comment: @ivan I fixed answer